# C# WPF How to change window title of all opened windows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have .NET Core app with WPF. I am trying to convert it to use DI and MVVM pattern.

I am stuck now. At the application startup I subscribe for some events. Event handler process it and change title of all opened windows.

Something like:

```
    protected void OnSomething(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            foreach (Window window in App.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (window.Title.EndsWith("something"))
                {
                    window.Title = window.Title.Substring(0, window.Title.Length - "something".Length);
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    protected void OnSomethingElse(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            foreach (Window window in App.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (!window.Title.EndsWith("something"))
                {
                    window.Title = window.Title + "something";
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

I would like to move window title construction into ViewModel of given window. Lets say:

`public string WindowTitle => "My title" + (currentState ? "something" : string.Empty);`

What is the best approach to update title of all opened windows? I believe that I can not change title in the way I am doing it right now. And I feel current way is not the right/best way.

Comment: Add a property of title in your ViewModel, set Window.DataContext as VM, and Binding Title

Comment: But how to change title property of all viewmodels of all currently opened windows?

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach.
Create a resource like this:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    [...]
    <system:String x:Key="AppTitle">Default App Title</system:String>
    [...]
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And set that resource as your window title:

```xml
<Window 
    [...]
    Title="{DynamicResource AppTitle}">
    [...]
</Window>
```

Note: it should be a **`DynamicResource`**.

Then create a utility method like this:

```cs
public class Utils {
  public static void ChangeAppTitle(string title) {
      Application.Current.Resources["AppTitle"] = title;
  }
}
```

Now we can access to this method in entire application.
And finally you can use it like this:

```
public class SampleViewModel {
    private void SampleMethod() {
        Utils.ChangeAppTitle("New app title");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice idea!

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario I would use my self-written EventService. This EventService looks like:

```
public class EventService<T>
{
    private static EventService<T> instance;
    private static readonly object instanceLock = new object();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<Action<T>> > events;

    private EventServiceExt()
    {
        events = new Dictionary<string, List<Action<T>>>();
    }

    public static EventService<T> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (instanceLock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new EventService<T>();
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    
    public void Subscribe(string eventName,  Action<T> action)
    {
        lock (instanceLock)
        {
            if (events.ContainsKey(eventName))
                events[eventName].Add(action);
            else
                events.Add(eventName, new List<Action<T>>{ action });
        }
    }
    
    public void Raise(string eventName, T parameter)
    {
        lock (instanceLock)
        {
            if (events != null && (events.ContainsKey(eventName) && events[eventName] != null))
            {
                var actions = events[eventName];
                if (actions != null)
                {                   
                    foreach (var action in actions.Where(action => action != null))
                    {                           
                        action(parameter);                          
                    }               
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventName"></param>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    public void Unsubscribe(string eventName, Action<T> action)
    {
        lock (instanceLock)
        {
            if (events.ContainsKey(eventName) && events[eventName] != null && action != null)
            {
                List<Action<T>> actions = events[eventName];
                actions.Remove(action);
                if (actions.Count == 0)
                    events.Remove(eventName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can subscribe to an event in each window like:

`EventService<string>.Instance.Subscribe("windowtitlechanged", OnWindowTitleChanged);`

And if you want to change the window-title you just have to raise the event with:

`EventService<string>.Instance.Raise("windowtitlechanged", "My new window-title");`